# Can I preserve a Win 10 user profile when connecting to a new Azure AD?

Tags: azure, windows-10, entra-id

I have users that log in to Windows 10 desktops using Azure Active Directory, because their desktops have joined the organization.

I am about to move the custom domain name from the current Azure Tenant to a new Tenant (mainly to fix a very bad x.onmicrosoft.com tenant name). After the move, I want bob@example.com to continue to log in as bob@example.com, but Bob will of course be now connecting to a different Tenant.

Can I save Bob's profile on Win 10, or will it be lost because he will essentially be getting a new identity from the new Tenant?

Answer (score 1):

Because the new Office 365 tenant is also a new Azure AD tenant I'm assuming that when Bob logs into Windows 10 with his new Office 365 username it will create a new user profile for Bob, since it's technically a different user account.

Edit:

This is an interesting question. One that I haven't taken the time to look into. Looking at my own Azure AD joined computer the screenshot below shows the permissions on my user profile folder.

So even if two different users have the same username, they are two distinctly different security principals. The new user will not have permission to write to the existing user profile folder. I'm assuming that Windows will not grant the new user permissions to the existing user profile folder but will in fact create a new user profile folder for the new user. I'd be very curious to see what actually happens if you test this for yourself.

[image]

Comment: That's what I expect too. But the email identifier will not change. It will still be bob@example.com. So will the local profile (c:\users\bob) be overwritten or preserved I wonder?

Comment: Two different user accounts, even if the username (in any format) is the same, are two different user accounts and will create two different user profiles. This is a function of Windows. I'm assuming this will function the same with Azure AD user accounts, even if the username/UPN is the same.

Comment: That's getting to the nub of the issue. I agree they are two different user accounts. Given that the usernames will be identical, I'm wondering how Windows will handle the fact that c:\users\bob already exists. Will the old c:\users\bob folder get deletd and recreated, or overwritten, or reused preserving the contents?